# jQuery UI dragging - Cannot move on padding area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

jQuery UI dragging plugin - When I am setting padding `40px` on containment (parent) div Then dragging item start from `40px`, I need dragging item  drag from `0px`

```
<div class="parent" style="200px; height:100px; border:1px solid red; padding:30px;">
  <div  class="item" style="width:20px; height:20px">item</div>
 </div>


$( ".item" ).draggable({containment: "parent" });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/2017/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that, you can simply add another div inside the main one, and add the padding to this new `div`, removing the padding from the `div.parent`.

Then, when setting the draggable, just set the containment to the `div.parent` instead of just `parent`.

```js
$( ".item" ).draggable({containment: ".parent" });
```

```css
.item{
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="parent" style="200px; height:100px; border:1px solid red;">
  <div class="paddingDiv" style="padding: 30px;">
    <div  class="item" style="width:20px; height:20px">item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent" style="200px; height:100px; border:1px solid red;">
```

item

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.